# Google PubSub in Apache Spark 2.2.1

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to use Google Cloud PubSub within a Spark application. For simplicity let's just say that this application is Spark's shell. Trying to instantiate a `Publisher` throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`, which is most likely the result of dependency version conflicts. However, with a simple setup like this (just Spark and a Google Cloud PubSub dependency), I can't figure out how to resolve this issue.

```
bash-4.4# spark-shell --packages com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.105.0
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.google.cloud#google-cloud-pubsub added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.google.cloud#google-cloud-pubsub;1.105.0 in central
    found io.grpc#grpc-api;1.28.1 in central
    ...
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_212)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.newBuilder("topic").build
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/gax/grpc/InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider
  at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.PublisherStubSettings.defaultGrpcTransportProviderBuilder(PublisherStubSettings.java:225)
  at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminSettings.defaultGrpcTransportProviderBuilder(TopicAdminSettings.java:169)
  at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$Builder.<init>(Publisher.java:674)
  at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$Builder.<init>(Publisher.java:625)
  at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.newBuilder(Publisher.java:621)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 53 more
```

Is there any way to get this to work? I could change the pubsub dependency version, but not the Spark version.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to Google's Guava dependency conflict which is known to exist whenever using Spark + Google Libraries. The workaround (with Maven) is using the maven-shade-plugin.